# Proper way to align labels with nodes tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (A) at (1,1);
\coordinate (B) at (2,2);

\draw[->] (A) -- (B);

\draw[dashed] (0,0) rectangle (3,3) node (C) {};

\draw [solid] ($(A.south west)-(0,1.5)$) -- ++(0.5, 0) node [label =right:Signalling] {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I properly align the end of label, with the edge of rectangle in a automated way?

[image]

Comment: @cacamailg I added the picture. I hope that is okay.

Comment: I am interested in the `pgfplots` solution. Can you add a MWE?

Comment: The corners of the rectangle seem to have a problem. They should look like L-shape broken lines actually.

Comment: @Karl'sstudents I didn't understand what you mean. Instead of dashed you can use solid for the rectangle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two options;

With TikZ, you can use the name of the node for a later use in this context;

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (1,1);
\coordinate (B) at (2,2);
\draw[->] (A) -- (B);
\draw[dashed] (0,0) rectangle (3,3) node (C) {};

\draw node[% Note that we are inside a path not inside a node declaration
     anchor=east,
     append after command={([xshift=-2mm]\tikzlastnode.west) -- ++ (-0.5,0)}, 
     inner sep=0] at (3,-0.5) {Signalling};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with `pgfplots` by actually drawing a function instead of giving it as a path;

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis line style=dashed,
xtick=\empty,
ytick=\empty,
legend pos={south east}
]
\addplot[->,domain=1:2] {x};\addlegendentry{Signalling}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Just a question in the 1st solution: `[xshift=-2mm]\tikzlastnode.west` is the same as `($(\tikzlastnode.west) + (-2mm,0)$)`?

Comment: @cacamailg Yes, but then you don't need `calc` library